# Is it okay to reuse Alumiconn connectors?

Tags: electrical, wiring, old-house, aluminum-wiring

After having redone the aluminum-to-copper pigtails in my house's electrical outlets using [AlumiConn](http://www.kinginnovation.com/category-pages/products/alumiconn.php) connectors, I subsequently had to undo a few to debug a wiring problem. All I did is unscrew the connectors and take out the wires; I did not otherwise damage the connectors or the wires.

Is it safe and acceptable to screw the wires back in, or must I replace the connectors entirely?

I am worried about reusing the connectors because pulling the wires out means (1) I've lost some of the antioxidant paste inside the connector and (2) the aluminum wires have been pressed by the set screw, so the wires' strength may have been compromised. Even if I clip the ends of the wires and re-strip them before reinserting them, that still wouldn't address issue #1. However, I don't really know – maybe I'm being too paranoid. I tried to find guidelines but my Google-fu is failing me in this case. Are there requirements or guidelines for this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the manufacture does not suggest to reuse the connectors.

For instance, this document [here](https://www.kinginnovation.com/pics/db/docs/59-5010046AWAlumiConnREVN.pdf) states "Do not reuse" in the "product specifications & measurements" section.

Comment: I agree they are listed for 1 time use. When you pull them off a small amount of the compound is removed. Would anyone know? Probably not but having seen fires from al to copper is it worth a risk.+

Comment: Ah, shoot, how did I miss that on the package :-). Thanks. That settles it.

Comment: just wondering- where did you purchase you AlumiCon connectors? I need to get some for my aluminum wiring.

Comment: Meh, at the end of the day they are lug connectors, which are infinitely reusable, just make sure to replace the paste.   The real question is whether "do not reuse" is a condition of the product's UL listing, or just a marketing claim to sell more Alumiconms.

Comment: @Harper, almost certainly BOTH!

Comment: @CFella In the US, they are available from the big home remodeling/DIY stores (e.g., HomeDepot, Lowe's) as well as from Amazon. I have to believe they would also be available from electrician's specialty stores too. BTW, I can't find the 2-port versions in the two big stores, so those I had to order those from Amazon.

Comment: thanks, i had the company send me some free samples a while back. Signed up to get some more free ones but they haven't sent it. probably because i already got them. but they did send me a couple of the 2-port versions for free. Go to their website and sign up for a free sample